# Firebase instance Id returns null

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating push notification for Firebase according to docs I have put google-services.json in my project my gradle are as follows.

Top level gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Project Level Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile project(':humanapi-sdk')
        compile files('libs/Android_iwown_Ble.jar')
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }

        compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0'
        compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:24.2.0'

        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'


    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In my activity code

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.i(TAG,"Firebase token: "+token);
```

token returned is always null

Comment: Can you please post your manifest file over here?

Comment: @dhuma1981I had manifest permission jumbled up fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Its completely wrong !!!!
you can only get the id in the FirebaseInstanceIdService !

It is revoked automatically and can not be done manually.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
}
```

Do not forget to add the service to your manifest too.

Comment: I have added a service as well but refresh token never gets printed. And moreover firbase sample app on github has a call in main activity as well

Answer (score -1):

Setting up everything from firebase setup guide works well but sometime its not working. token is not generated.

"After digging up thru old implementations of FCM and generated manifests, I can now say that manifest merger is the problem.

Solution for this problem is adding these classes to the apps manifest manualy"

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<service
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.fc.debug" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
    android:exported="false" />
<!--

-->
<service
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="com.fc.debug.firebaseinitprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:initOrder="100" />

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40009448/5740236