# FirebaseInstanceIdService getToken returning null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im trying to add FCM notifications to my app, but for some reason

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

is returning null.

Since im not getting any stacktrace my best guess is that FirebaseInstanceIdService is not working

- Google Play Services version: 9.6.1
- Firebase-messaging version : 9.6.1
- added json config file from FirebaseConsole (Tried single file with 2 clients inside it, one for debug and one for release build) and 2 files each for respective build

Iw applied google services plugin at the bottom of my modules gradle script 
Included google services in projects root gradle script

Created 2 services from the officail docs:

```
public class MyFirebaseInsanceIDService  extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    PreferencesHelper.putSharedPreferencesString(Constants.User.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS, refreshedToken);

    Log.e("TOKEN", "Token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
}
```

}

And the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.fc.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="fctest"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="${appName}${appNameSuffix}"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:node="replace">

    <service
        android:name="com.fc.test.MyFirebaseInsanceIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.fc.test.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.fc.test.view.splash.Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CenterAnimation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

root Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = '24.0.1'
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 24
    supportLibraryVersion = '24.2.1'
}
```

and the main part of the modules Gradle

```
    dependencies {
    final PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = '9.6.1'
    final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '24.2.1'
    final RETROFIT_VERSION = '2.1.0'
    final DAGGER_VERSION = '2.5'
    final DEXMAKER_VERSION = '1.4'
    final HAMCREST_VERSION = '1.3'
    final ESPRESSO_VERSION = '2.2.1'
    final RUNNER_VERSION = '0.4'
    final BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION = '8.1.0'
    def daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    def jUnit = "junit:junit:4.12"
    def mockito = "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    // App Dependencies
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

- Note that im using `tools:node="replace"`  in my root application tag.
  Is it possible that `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is not added to the manifest since it has the same intent filter as mine `FirebaseInstanceService` and thus not being called?

So my question here would be is there something wrong it the official docs or in my implementation that should cause the Instance token to be null?

Comment: Is a current version of Google Play Services installed on your device or emulator?

Comment: Yeah im testing this on my device GS version 9.6.83

Comment: Check that the `Sender ID` shown on the Cloud Messaging tab of the Project Settings at the Firebase Console matches the `project_number` included in your google-services.json file.

Comment: @qbix yeah they are the same

Comment: I starting to think you are right about `tools:node="replace"` being the problem, but don't know specifically why.  Is it possible to build you app without it?

Comment: @qbix Hm i had the same problem with the Braintree SDK, since the manifest merger did not merge their activitys in my manifest. And no, my build is failing since i have multiple libraries which have android:label defined in root application tags. Iw solved the problem with the Braintree by manualy adding their Activity to my manifest,il try to dig default FCM receivers to manualy include them in manifest

Comment: Hi @qbix, `tools:node="replace"` is not required in the manifest. Why do you need it? It's quite possible that it's blocking the manifest merging.
Out of curiosity, why are you using that tag ?

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini: Your comment was addressed to me but should have been for @Ivan.  He will have to explain why is using `tools:node="replace"`.  It was the cause of the problem, which he briefly described in his answer below.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini im having multiple libraries in my project and some of them have application properties (icon, label, etc...) defined in their manifests application tags. Since those properties produce conflicts during build time i have to replace every conflict from low level manifests (library manifest) with values defined in my top level (my app manifest) and thus `tools:node="replace"`
More info https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging up thru old implementations of FCM and generated manifests, I can now say that manifest merger is the problem.

Solution for this problem is adding these classes to the apps manifest manualy

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.fc.debug" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />
    <!--

    -->
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="com.fc.debug.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

While I was doing the migration I had a problem, it was that I didn't receive any Notification. To solve this and If you have your GCM working, don't forget to include your sender ID when you get the Firebase Token. To consult this ID you have to navigate to your Firebase project and click Project Name. Click the Setting icon and select "Project Setting" menu Select "Could Messaging" tab and use sender ID on the page.

And when says to code this:

```
     token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

You have to use this:

```
     token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("YOUR_SENDER_ID", "FCM");
```

It works for me, I hope this helps you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken();
```

Answer (score -1):

First genarate "google-services.json" and Add this file in your android studio Like this  projectFolder/APP/google-services.json

Add classpath to top level build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Add following plugin and dependencies in app’s build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}
```

**Add following Firebase services in your java files**

FirebaseIDService.java

```
package com.galleonsoft.firebase.push;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
package com.galleonsoft.firebase.push;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMEssagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

Add service in your AndroidMainifest.xml file

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMEssagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Iw done all of this, and btw you have an error in your example 

'apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'' should go on the bottom of the apps module

Comment: Remember internet permission in mainifest files
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Thank you :) but I have that as well

Comment: add gradle code in both files.

And Get google-services.json files from firebase and put in app folder.