# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); returning null... but this happened suddenly I cant understand

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using this line of code:-

```
String devicetoken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

But this is ***returning null*** every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseInstanceIdService getToken returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008076/firebaseinstanceidservice-gettoken-returning-null)

Comment: **Note:** If google play service hung or not running, then FCM return token = null