# FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token returns null

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a Xamarin.Android application targeting Oreo 8.1. I integrated Firebase notifications in my application. It was working fine till now but since last week I am getting strange error where `var token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;` returns null. Also my FirebaseInstanceIdService does not get invoke when my app is installed for the first time on user's device.

I have tried several solutions including [firebaseinstanceidservice-gettoken-returning-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008076/)

I tried to clean my solution several times even deleted bin and obj folders but still no use. I even tried to create new Firebase console app's google-services.json file but still receiving the same problem.

I will really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: build action of google-services.json file should be GoogleServiceJson.

Comment: show me your manifest and your FirebaseInstanceIdService