# Android apk not opening even on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android app is not opening. I really don't know why. any help will be appreciated. thanks! btw it has google maps and firebase in it.

**Both the `gradle` files are at the bottom**

**below is the output on the logcat / run:**

```
                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.lrtapp.ardentmap, PID: 2781
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lrtapp.ardentmap/com.lrtapp.ardentmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
                      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
                      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110)
                      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                      at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:145)
                      at com.lrtapp.ardentmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7130)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7121)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060) 
                      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
                      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110) 
                      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826) 
I/rtapp.ardentma: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 7646(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1588KB/3MB, paused 8.189ms total 105.027ms
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2781 SIG: 9
Application terminated.                   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
```

below are the  codes:

**Main Activity Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    private Button btnAbout;
    private Button btnContact;
    private Button btnVideos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openAbout();
            }
        });

        btnContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
        btnContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openContact();
            }
        });

        btnVideos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVideos);
        btnVideos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openVideos();
            }
        });

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(Constants.CHANNEL_ID, Constants.CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            mChannel.setDescription(Constants.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);

            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400 ,500 ,400, 300, 200, 400});

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        common.currentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.d("My Token", common.currentToken);

        if(isServicesOK())

            init();
    }

    private void init(){

        Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
        btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isServicesOK(){
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");

        int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);

        if(available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            //everything is okay
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: Google Play services is working");
            return true;
        }else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){
            // an error occured but we can resolve it
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: an error occured but we can fix it");
            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "we cant make map requests", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void openAbout(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openContact(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openVideos(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Videos.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

**FirebaseMessagingService Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;


import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService";

    public FirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        MyNotificationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .displayNotification(title, body);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {

    }

}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lrtapp.ardentmap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/erlogo"
        android:label="EaseRoute"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyALC_Pis5w391INiqcvnXO7dipxuMP0-JA" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Contact" />
        <activity android:name=".Videos"></activity>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My Notification Manager Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyNotificationManager {

    private Context mCtx;
    private static MyNotificationManager mInstance;

    private MyNotificationManager(Context context){
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyNotificationManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new MyNotificationManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void displayNotification(String title, String body){

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(mNotificationManager != null){
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }

    }
}
```

**Constants Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

public class Constants {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "mychannelid";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "mychannelname";
    public static final String CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION = "myDescription";

}
```

**Class for google map**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //widgets
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;

    //vars

    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mSearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);

        getLocationPermission();

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: Initializing");

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        ||  keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //execute method for searching
                    geoLocate();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");

        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "GeoLocate: found a Location: " +address.toString());

           // Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT()).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the device's current location.");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted){

                final com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Found Location");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                                moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                        DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                        "My Location");

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current Location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " +latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));

        if(!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);

            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();

    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            initMap();

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted.");
                    //initializing map
                    initMap();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

}
```

**Project Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



**Module/App Gradle**
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lrtapp.ardentmap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'

    //Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any kind of answer will be very appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you publish the crash logs?

Comment: Hi, im sorry im kinda new to this. But, where could i find it?

Comment: I mean because it just closes

Comment: After i open / open on emulator the app closes

Comment: You can find error logs in `logcat` below in Android Studio

Comment: What is the error that you get? Please responde with @.

Comment: @Zeke please paste the `logcat` output of the crash; which can be found in the `logcat` tab of Android Studio... else all of your code does not really help to understand, what the issue with it may be.

Comment: @MartinZeitler here it is bro, ill just edit my post and place it at the top of the codes.

Comment: @AlexMamo I just posted another answer. sorry for my late response. Btw, I also included it on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:145)
                  at com.lrtapp.ardentmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
```

At line 79 of your logging common.currentToken which is null.

```
  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

From that point on, you can see this answer with some possibilities why your token is returning null:

[FirebaseInstanceIdService getToken returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008076/firebaseinstanceidservice-gettoken-returning-null)

A quick dirty fix is to comment that line (79) but your notifications won´t work.

Comment: oh, here it is. sorry i didnt see your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change Line 79 in MainActivity

> Log.d("My Token", common.currentToken + "");

Comment: It will solve it, but would not address the root cause.

Comment: What should i place inside the " " ? or should i leave it blank?

Comment: @Zeke You can keep it blank.

Comment: @CuriousMind i got curious bro, what do you mean by address the root cause?

Comment: @zeke if it solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the correct button next to answer.

Comment: @KiranMalvi I just did, it's already running and im about to try if it can receive notifications.

Comment: You should be curious man - I mean why is your token is returning null? That is the problem, not logging is the sympton. 
Your Log.d line writes a debug info to the logcat. It was giving error cause the line was null - the root cause being your token was returning null. You should fix that, instead of adding "" to the log entry in order for the code to go on. The token will be needed later on the code (perhaps for notifications) and something won´t work. Please read my answer and the link provided in it - this is not the correct answer, just a quick workaround for the code to go on.

Comment: @CuriousMind maybe that is why im not getting a refreshed token? may i ask again, where is the link? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but the steps for you to follow to get logs. 
When you run app on emulator, open run window on Android Studio, you can find it left corner below.
 [image: Like shown in screenshot]

In this window you can find the log, just copy and paste that log here, so we can help.

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: Yes agreed!, to answer the question, we need to logcat, and as it seems user is new to android studio, needed to provide screenshot which I can not upload in comment, hence answered. Although I will mention it explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, just got home

Comment: that's what the comment section above is ordinary intended for - won't down-vote or flag it... but please consider replacing it with an actual attempt at an answer, once more information is available.

Comment: I added it just now. i added it on my question and it was at the top

Answer (score 0):

from what I can tell at sight, the `build.gradle` lacks the following dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
```

possibly also:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"
```

please add those at first - and then add the `logcat` output to the question, if still required.