# Default firebase application not initialized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate FCM in one of my Android App. I have followed the instructions as per documentation and my POC app is working fine. When I follow the same steps, in my final app, which is a multidex app, it is not working. I am getting an Illegal state exception with the message that Default Firebase application has not been initialized. My package name (defined in manifest file) and application ID (as defined in gradle file) are different, and in the google-services.json file, it hase taken the application id in the client info section. I have tried searching in net, gone through several stack overflow discussions, but none of the suggestions did work for me.

Section from Manifest file:

```
<service
  android:name=".services.JBFirebaseMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Initialization code in activity:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w("", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                        return;
                    }
                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    if (task.getResult() != null) {
                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        // Log
                        String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
                        Log.d("", msg);
                        LogHelper.writeLog(null,msg);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645728/2633909 are you sure you have done all these.

Answer (score -1):

Try this And you have to add the `google-services.json` file from the firebase console.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String deviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In my case FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() gives null.

Comment: @NibirChakraborty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008076/firebaseinstanceidservice-gettoken-returning-null

Comment: This is happen only coz of your one small mistake you have double check your code with Google doc

Comment: Jaydip, could you please be little more specific to point out the mistake I have made. Thank You.

Comment: Just go through your code and this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Thanks Jaydip. All the mentioned steps in the provided links are actually done. Still getting the error.

Comment: All the time, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() returns null